# jquery.jqGrid.js 5.2.0 Cross-Site Scripting: DOM on .val() line

Tags: jqgrid, xss, fortify

After run in HP Fortify 19.2.1, it has found 129 critical issues.

**Cross-Site Scripting: DOM**

File: jquery.jqGrid.js:9220

```
for(var i in a2 ) {
    if( a2.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var val = $('input[name="'+i+'"]:checked',frm).val();
        $t.p.savedData[i] = (val !== undefined) ? val : a2[i];
    }
}
```

I tried to add **$.jgrid.htmlEncode()** outside the .val(), then scan again.The issue wasn't be detect.

`var val = $.jgrid.htmlEncode($('input[name="' + i + '"]:checked', frm).val());`

Is this the correct solution or Is there a better solution?

jqGrid Source Code Link: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v5.2.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The better solution is nothing to do.

Comment: @TonyTomov Hi Tony, because this issue is false positive?

Comment: I think that really this is too much and yes it is false positive.